# How to save a hash in a file and use it later in ruby?

Tags: ruby

So i got in big troubles with this exam at university because i am stuck with a part in my ruby code. I just can't figure out how

" If the user presses 2 the program shall ask for an employee number and afterwards search for the employee. If the program finds it, then print and if not, print a message saying it doesn’t have it."

My problem is that i'm not sure that the information is saved corectly in the file. But if it is... the problem is that the hash i've made isn't taking the information that already is saved in the file and only works with the information it has received last.

```
puts "Insert Registration number \n"
search = gets.chomp

hash = Hash.new()
hash = {(regnr) => (name)}
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key} \t | \t #{value}"
end

search =~ File.new("employees.txt", "r")

if hash.has_key? (search)
  print "The person you were looking for is "
  puts hash [search]
else
  puts "He isn't one of our employees"
end
```

I have to tell you guys that i have only been coding for one month and the school isn't taking me easy...

Comment: I don't understand this code. Why are you using a `Hash`? What is `regnr`? What is `name`? What is `employees.txt`? Please provide a [mcve] of the problem, including the actual error/unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You're using [=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `yaml`. Take a look around the web for some examples on using YAML. It's a structured markup that can represent hashes. You can easily dump and load simple ruby objects like hashes and arrays.

```
require 'yaml'

parsed = begin
  employee_hash = YAML.load(File.open("employees.yml"))
rescue ArgumentError => e
  puts "Could not parse YAML: #{e.message}"
end
```